# access jQuery in content_script chrome extension

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm unable to load jQuery for use in my `contentscript.js` file. I've seen numerous posts suggesting that this method will work, but when I run `console.log($)` from my `contentscript.js` file I get undefined. `jquery-3.3.1.min.js` is included in the extension directory.

```
{
  "name": "Watch",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "icons": { "16": "16.png",
           "48": "48.png",
          "128": "128.png" },
  "description": "sets screen time for chrome",
   "background": {
    "scripts": ["counter.js","background.js"],
    "persistent": false
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["https://*/*","https://*/*"],
      "js": ["jquery-3.3.1.min.js", "counter.js", "contentscript.js"],
      "css": ["style.css"]
    }
  ],
  "permissions": [
    "tabs",
    "storage"
  ]
}
```

Comment: The posted code isn't sufficient to identify the problem. It might  be faster to diagnose if you upload a zip of your extension somewhere and post a link in a comment below. BTW you have https declared twice, and counter.js is used in two different contexts which isn't necessarily a problem but it could be.

Comment: https://sonoclipshare.com/Thad.Watch.zip Thanks.

Comment: Your contentscript.js puts the code into the page context by running it as a DOM script element - outside of the isolated world of content scripts where jQuery declared in manifest.json runs. I see no need here for this very special trick used to get page variables and spoof page code. Remove it.

Comment: I'll give it a whirl. I'm can't remember the reason I was doing that in the first place, I'll take a look and see if it breaks anything.

Comment: @wOxxOm thanks.  that worked.